# VI - How to Replace text between the 6th comma and the 9th comma

Tags: regex, vim

In VIM, How to use regexp or other skills to remove the period between the 6th comma and the 9th comma for the **multiple lines** of the following texts?

Change from:
`4,Afghanistan,2,Medium,1951,1951.5`**,4134.756,3705.395,7840.151,**`12.009`
`4,Afghanistan,5,Constant fertility,2023,2023.5`**,21628.67,20554.282,42182.952,**`64.613`

To:
`4,Afghanistan,2,Medium,1951,1951.5`**,4134756,3705395,7840151,**`12.009`
`4,Afghanistan,5,Constant fertility,2023,2023.5`**,2162867,20554282,42182952,**`64.613`

I have a csv file with lots of similar records like this.
As the position of the 6th and 9th comma may not be in the same column,
I can't use block-wise visual mode to delete those periods.

One way to do this is to split comma to columns in excel and replace it in the columns of excel. But my csv file is more than 100 MegaBytes and my computer is too slow to do it.

Per my vi and regexp knowledge, I could use below regexp to locate the position of the 6th comma, but that's not enough.
`/\([^,]*,\)\{-6}`

Is there any advanced regexp usages to remove the period between the 6th comma and the 9th comma in a multi-line csv file?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description, I have updated my question and what I have tried.

Comment: Would you consider a better tool for this like `awk`?

Comment: Is `fertility` appearing on a new line in 2nd record?

Comment: yes, and there are many other lines in the csv file which have variable length, the only way to differentiate it is the comma,

Comment: I'll study the usage of awk now

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question well, but I hope I could explain it in more details to answer your question, the file is csv file, each line is comma separated, the content between two commas is an item, and the lines are separated by \n

Comment: I understand csv part but in a csv records are separated by newline only. However here in 2nd record you have a line break **within a record** i.e. between `Constant` and  `fertility`

Comment: Sorry, in raw data, there is no line break between Constant and Fertility, it's actually a space character, if you click edit to view my post, it looks like there is a line break between Constant and Fertility, but it's actually a space character

Comment: ok that's what I asked earlier and you answered `yes, fertility is on a new line`

Comment: Very sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments you can use a simple awk like this:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {for (i=7; i<=9; ++i) sub(/\./, "", $i)} 1' file.csv

4,Afghanistan,2,Medium,1951,1951.5,4134756,3705395,7840151,12.009
4,Afghanistan,5,Constant fertility,2023,2023.5,2162867,20554282,42182952,64.613
```

Comment: Great thanks for the neat solution! Two more questions, first, what's the number `1` used for in this solution? I just learned some basic knowledge of awk, but it's hard for me to find out the usage of `1`. Second, how to write the change back to the csv file with awk?

Comment: `1` (or any non-zero number) is a short hand condition+action to print all records in awk. To save changes inline use `awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {for (i=7; i<=9; ++i) sub(/\./, "", $i)} 1' file.csv` if you're using `gnu` version of awk. Otherwise traditional `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {for (i=7; i<=9; ++i) sub(/\./, "", $i)} 1' file.csv > _tmp && mv _tmp file.csv` would work

Comment: yes, the second solution with output redirector > works, my awk is gawk, so I'm trying for the "awk -i" solution

Answer (score 3):

Here we go with a pure Vim solution:

```
:%normal 6f,v3f,:s/\%V.\+\%V/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\.','','g')/
```

- `:[range]normal <command>` executes normal mode command `<command>` on every line covered by `[range]`. See `:help :normal`.
- `%` is a range that covers the whole buffer so the command will be executed on every line. See `:help :range` if your needs are different.
- `6f,` moves the cursor on the 6th `,` on the current line. See `:help f`.
- `v3f,` starts a visual selection that extends to the third `,` to the right, effectively covering the text from the 6th `,` to the 9th `,`.
- `:s/<pattern>/<replacement>` substitutes the first occurence of `<pattern>` in the current line with `<replacement>`. See `:h :s`.
- `\%V.\+\%V` is our pattern. The `\%V` at the beginning and end limit the search to the last visual selection and `.\+` just means "1 or more of any character", so our substitution only works on the text from the 6th `,` to the 9th `,`. See `:help \%V` and `:help \+`.
- The `<replacement>` part of the command starts with `\=<expression>`, a special item that allows us to use the output of `<expression>` as replacement. See `:help sub-replace-expression`.
- Our expression is `substitute(submatch(0),'\.','','g')` which substitutes every (`'g'`) literal `.` (`'\.'`) in the whole match of the parent substitution (`submatch(0)`) with nothing (`''`), effectively removing them. See `:help substitute()`and `:help submatch()`.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing the powerful vi solution. Just some comments, first, `f6,` and `vf3,` should be changed to `6f,` and `v3f,` because `f6,` might match literal `6` firstly other than the `,`. Second, when I run this command `:normal f6,vf3,:s/\%V.\+\%V/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\.','','g')/` for a single line text, it doesn't work. But it works if I split it to two commands as below:  
`:normal f6,vf3,  //click enter`  
`:s/\%V.\+\%V/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\.','','g')/  //click enter`  
Do you know the reason?

Comment: The following command works for single line replacement: `:exe ':normal 6f,v3f,'|:s/\%V.\+\%V/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\.','','g')/`, but I can't apply it to the whole file with the range symbol %

Comment: Oh god… where did I pull those `f6,` and `vf3,` from?

Answer (score 1):

visual select and use `:s/\%V\.//g` on the selection

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description, as the position of the 6th and 9th comma may not be in the same column in a multi-line file, I can't use block-wise visual mode to delete those periods.